# Spring JPA specification

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to use AND OR operator in same query as below using spring JPA Specification:-

```
SELECT * FROM areatbl where MAXIMUM = 100 and  areacode = 1 or areacode=3;
```

Can some one please guide me how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use any popular JPA implementation (like Hibernate, Eclipse Link, Open JPA) and integrate it into your Spring container.
There are plenty of Hibernate + Spring tutorials in the web - it is the most popular combination of tools